# jenkins arifacts server configuration for nexus

Tags: jenkins

I am newly learning Jenkins CI tool. I have issue while deploying artifacts from Jenkins to nexus. Here i attached screen shot Jenkins error snap with my pom file and maven setting file configuration.

[image: Nexus Arifactory servers]

Pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
<snapshotRepository>
  <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
  <url>http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
</snapshotRepository>
```

maven/setting.xml

```
<server>
<id>nexus-snapshots</id>
<username>admin</username>
<password>admin123</password>
```

Could please some one help me on this issue ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the artifactory plugin to upload to nexus, artifactory is a different repository manager.

Also your url to nexus is wrong, should be something like http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/dev_repo

Also if you've already configured your maven to upload to a repo, then just run mvn publish.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for Your reply. Here i have two questions, while configuring Jenkins to upload artifacts via jenkins which plugin i have to use ? and second thing could you please give me any example how to co figure this (dev_repo)     ttp://localhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/dev_repo.

Comment: I have already installed nexus-artifact-uploader plugin also.